# Linux - Holding down a key acts like key repeating

Tags: linux, debian, keyboard, mate-desktop

I'm running Debian 10 with MATE GUI and even when I disabled "Key presses repeat when key is held down", the key i'm holding still acts like I'm pressing it:

[image]

Are there any other option I'm missing?

Edit: Just found using keyboardchecker.com that it does not recognize when I'm pressing SHIFT (although it works like it should). Weirdly, the SHIFT key is being recognized like it should in a Win10 KVM guest OS. It's the only key that when hold doesn't act like pressed.